# run-time error 1004 on backup macro that worked before and works on other users

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, backup

I have a backup macro that runs every time when I save my excel file and saves a copy of the workbook into a folder.

Now I got a new computer where I use the same file, and it does not work anymore, I get run-time error 1004.

My co worker uses the same excel file and the same computer with another user and for him the macro works perfectly as it used to work for me on the other computer.

Code:

```
'backup

ora = ".h" & Hour(Now)
bufolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\excel_backups"
If Len(Dir(bufolder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
   MkDir bufolder
End If
excfile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\excel_backups\backup_" & Format(Date, "yyyy/mm/dd") & ora & "_" & ActiveWorkbook.name
If Dir(excfile) = "" Then
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=bufolder & "\backup_" & Format(Date, "yyyy/mm/dd") & ora & "_" & ActiveWorkbook.name
End If
```

Edit: I get the error on line:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=bufolder & "\backup_" & Format(Date, "yyyy/mm/dd") & ora & "_" & ActiveWorkbook.name
```

It says:

> Microsoft Office Excel cannot access the file '...' 
>   There are several
>   possible reasons:
>
> The file name of path does not exit. The file is being used by another
>   program. The Workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a

I don't think any of these problems may cause the problem.

Thank you for your time

Comment: What is the exact error and on what line do you receive it?

Comment: Is it possible that the file cannot be saved because you are attempting to save the file name with your date formatted as "yyyy/mm/dd"? My computer will not allow me to save a file name with backslashes in it. Try changing the Format function to `Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")`.

Comment: @TheEngineer: Thank you, this one solved the problem, but I don't understand why was it working before. I taught it was some user specific error.

Comment: @TheEngineer If you write your comment as an answer, I will rate it up and accept it as an answer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It may be possible that some computers or operating systems allow backslashes in file names. I've added my comment as an answer. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file cannot be saved because you are attempting to save the file name with your date formatted as "yyyy/mm/dd"? My computer will not allow me to save a file name with backslashes in it. Try changing the Format function to `Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")`.